# pytorch .stack final shape after .squeeze

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I had a pandas dataframe 200 columns by 2500 rows which I made it into a tensor

```
tensor = torch.tensor(df.values)
tensor.size() => ([2500,200])
```

which i chunked and enumerated

```
list=[]
for i,chunk in enumerate(tensor.chunk(100,dim=0))
    chunk.size =>([25,200])
    output = hiddenlayer(chunks)
    output.size() => ([25,1])
    list += output
```

chunks were fed through some layers and outputted as 1 feature tensors. So now I have a list of 100 tensors, each with 25 blocks of 1, 100x25x1

so i

```
stacked = torch.stack(list, 1).squeeze(2)
stacked.size()=([25,100])
```

I've played around with the stacking and squeezing but i can't seem to get back to ([2500,1]) which is what I want. Am I missing something? If you could quickly help me understand what stacking and squeezing is doing and why it's not working for me I'd be forever in your debt! Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do `list.append(output)`? It's probably also a good practice not name your list `list` since that's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming `list` to `tensor_list` since it's bad practice to use reserved keywords as variable names.

```
tensor_list =[]
for i,chunk in enumerate(tensor.chunk(100,dim=0)):
    output = hiddenlayer(chunk).squeeze()
    tensor_list.append(output)

result = torch.reshape(torch.stack(tensor_list,0), (-1, 1))
```

result.size() should now return `torch.Size([2500, 1])`

Comment: Thanks! it worked! so torch.stack(tensor_list,0) stacks the list 'vertically' and the reshape (-1,1) squeezes the tensors together? how did you get the -1 dimension for reshape? a_list += an_item is the same as a_list.append(an_item)

Comment: just to clarifiy dimension 0 and dimension 1 on x,y,z array, i'm just trying to wrap my head around dimension -1. ps i tried to draw a matrix but i couldn't here lol

Comment: Lol, so -1 simply is a way to leave calculating the dimensions to PyTorch. If the output tensor is supposed to be 2-dimensional and we know what one of them should be (`1` in your case), we are allowed to specify the remaining dimension as `-1` and the code infers it. As a general rule, when reshaping, any one dimension can be set to `-1`. You can read more about this method [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape).

PS: if this solution works for you, could you set it as an "accepted" answer pls?